# Datagrid operation is not valid while itemssource is in use

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I want to delete the records of datagrid by using code and update the database.
i use the following code for deleting records from datagrid `datagrid1.items.RemoveAt(0)`,
and this line give a Error msg:

> operation is not valid while itemssource is in use

But if i delete the record of datagrid using keyboard delete button and then pressing `btnUpdate_Click` for updating the database, then it works fine without no error.

so please give me the proper reason why this happen.
I hope you all understand my problem.
My All code is here:

```
Dim db As New dbconnect()
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
Dim cmdBuild As MySqlCommandBuilder
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable

Private Sub btn_DayBook_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn_DayBook.Click


    cmd = New MySqlCommand("select * from transactions", db.conn)
    dt = New DataTable()
    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGrid1.DataContext = dt
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
    cmdBuild = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)

End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        Try
            cmdBuild.GetUpdateCommand()
            da.Update(dt)
            btn_DayBook_Click(sender, e)
            MsgBox("Record Updated")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub



 Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Try

            DataGrid1.Items.RemoveAt(DataGrid1.SelectedIndex)
            DataGrid1.Items.Refresh()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

        Try

            cmdBuild.GetDeleteCommand()
            da.Update(dt)

            MsgBox("Record Deleted")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        btn_DayBook_Click(sender, e)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, collection controls provide two main ways to set or access data. When setting data, you can either use the `ItemsSource` property *or* you can use the `Items` property. If you use the `ItemsSource` property as you have, then to manipulate the items in the collection control, you simply manipulate the items from the data collection that is data bound to that control.

In your case, you could maintain a reference to your `DataTable` and alter its rows and columns to update the UI. However, when editing data in this way, you need a way for changes to be updated in the UI. Because of this, we generally create custom classes that represent our data and implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Then we would iterate through our incoming data, row by row, populating an `ObservableCollection<YourDataType>` with data. This would then be data bound to the `ItemsSource` property of the collection control and changes could then be made by editing the items in the data bound collection. Using this method is often combined with data binding the `itemsControl.SelectedItem` property to an object of type `YourDataType` in your view model, or code behind. This is the preferred way to work with collection controls in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

if would be easier if do a little bit more wpf with binding and mvvm

- you would have a collection (at best OberservableCollection of your Datatype)
- you would bind this collection as ItemsSource to your datagrid
- you just alter your collection with Clear(), Add(), Remove() and your grid is "magically" display this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you attach an itemsource to the datagrid then you need to modify the collection you have used as an itemsource not in the way you have done above.

When you press delete on the keyboard the datagrid is handling this for you and deleting the item from your itemsource instead of the datagrids items.